# How to add custom analyzer to mapping ElasticSearch-2.3.5 for partial searching?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch-2.3.5. I want to add my custom analyzer to mapping while index creating.

`PUT /library`

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "15",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "index_ngram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "search_term_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": "lowercase"
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "book": {
        "properties": {
          "Id": {
            "type": "long",
            "search_analyzer": "search_term_analyzer",
            "index_analyzer": "index_ngram_analyzer",
            "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"
          },
          "Title": {
            "type": "string",
            "search_analyzer": "search_term_analyzer",
            "index_analyzer": "index_ngram_analyzer",
            "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I take a template example from [official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-create-index.html).

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error trying to execute the first part of code. There is my error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "analyzer [search_term_analyzer] not found for field [Title]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [book]: analyzer [search_term_analyzer] not found for field [Title]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "analyzer [search_term_analyzer] not found for field [Title]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I can do it if I put my `mappings` inside of `settings`, but I think that it is wrong way. So I try to find my book by using a part of title. I have the "King Arthur" book for example. My query looks like this:

`POST /library/book/_search`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "Title": "kin"
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing will be found. What I do wrong? Could you help me? It seems my analyzer and tokenizer don't work. How can I get the terms "k", "i", "ki", "king" etc.? Because I think that I have only two terms right now. There are 'king' and 'arthur'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced the `search_term_analyzer` analyzer, it should be inside the `analyzer` section

```
PUT /library
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "15",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "index_ngram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "search_term_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "book": {
        "properties": {
          "Id": {
            "type": "long",         <---- you probably need to make this a string or remove the analyzers
            "search_analyzer": "search_term_analyzer",
            "analyzer": "index_ngram_analyzer",
            "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"
          },
          "Title": {
            "type": "string",
            "search_analyzer": "search_term_analyzer",
            "analyzer": "index_ngram_analyzer",
            "term_vector":"with_positions_offsets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Also make sure to use `analyzer` instead of `index_analyzer`, the latter as been deprecated in ES 2.x

Comment: I'm sorry, but something went wrong. Maybe I should put my search analyzer before analyzer? `"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "analyzer on field [Title] must be set when search_analyzer is set"
      }`

Comment: You simply need to replace `index_analyzer` with `analyzer` because the former was deprecated in ES 2.x.

Comment: Maybe be API has another changes because I got another error: `{
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [Id] has unsupported parameters:  [search_analyzer : search_term_analyzer] [analyzer : index_ngram_analyzer] [term_vector : with_positions_offsets]"
      }`

Comment: You cannot set an analyzer on a field with type `long`. Either change that to `string` or remove the analyzers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I fight with this problem about two days.